# How to get rid of warning messages on virtual include statement after making a new session through session_start()?

Tags: php, session-cookies

### Problem And Explanation:

I am not quite familiar on how to properly start a session with a virtual include in which I am trying to create a welcome page for a user, but I keep getting  a warning on my one `virtual(...)` statement. I will list the error down below.  I am sure it couldn't be to hard of a fix, but I can't seem to get rid of it.

#### Code

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
//line below is where I get the error
<?php virtual('../common/headerhw8.html'); ?>
<body>
<?php
echo'Welcome to user welcome page';
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: ../php/login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Error

`virtual(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`

Comment: What is the content of `../common/headerhw8.html`?

Comment: Why are you using that at all? What do you need apache to parse?

Comment: Maybe you want https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php instead?